# Java Pattern for Scoring/Ranking Albums

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm building a relatively simple algorithm to score albums based on several criteria -- for example, listen count, audio quality, star reviews, existence of album artwork, etc. I'm trying to decide what the best design pattern for this algorithm would be, and I would love input. Right now, I feel like Builder best addresses the problem.

Here are some more details:

1. Depending on the service that's using the Scorer, the end user can choose which criteria to include or exclude. For example, one service might want to consider star reviews while a different service might not want to score based on star reviews. Ultimately, it should be up to the user to build their scorer however they want.
2. The inputs for the criteria range from int to String to boolean and other types.
3. Scores are calculated on each individual album. Other albums do not affect an album's score.
4. Some baseline criteria must be included. For example, at the very least, the scorer must use listen count and audio quality. As referenced by the first point, on top of those minimum criteria, users can include other criteria.
5. The input to the algorithm is an album with its accompanying data: [ALBUM, LISTEN COUNT, AUDIO QUALITY, STAR REVIEWS, etc...]

The Builder pattern seems to apply best here because it would allow users to build their own algorithm while avoiding telescoping. Thoughts? Are there other patterns I should consider including with the Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the data you need for the various criteria are contained within the album data and each criteria contributes to the overall score I would suggest turning each criteria into a Java Function that transforms an album into a score.  Then for all selected criteria, run the criteria functions on the album and merge the individual results into a single score.  You could then turn the criteria into an enumeration which would make it easy to pass around the selected criteria into your scoring function

If each criteria is not equal, you could also return a weight factor (e.g. star review may be twice as important as listen count) with the score such that the contribution of a given criteria is (score * weight)/sum of weights

Answer (score 0):

There are two design questions here: constructing the scorer and applying the scorer. These questions are an opportunity for several design patterns.

**Builder** may be an appropriate solution to the first question, depending on the complexity of the scorer itself. The second question is a clear use case for the [Strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) (which the answer from @V3V is also describing). Each "scorer" is an algorithm; the strategy pattern is a design for substitutable algorithms. Baseline criteria for the algorithms may be implemented using a [Template method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).